# Why does an index entry generated from a listings' token preceeding a comma get rejected?

Tags: listings, indexing, expansion, makeindex

I'm trying to index the tokens in a listing, but they always get rejected if they are followed by a comma.

Here's `mwe.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{index={foobar}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    foobar, baz
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

`pdflatex mwe` produces `mwe.idx`:

```
\indexentry{{\ttfamily  foobar\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@ }}{1}
```

`makeindex mwe` however rejects the entry, as seen in `mwe.ilg`:

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [TeX Live 2018] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file mwe.idx...
!! Input index error (file = mwe.idx, line = 1):
   -- Extra `@' at position 44 of first argument.
done (0 entries accepted, 1 rejected).
Nothing written in mwe.ind.
Transcript written in mwe.ilg.
```

I feel like `\unhbox \voidb@x \kern \z@` shouldn't be there.
I figured out that's the expansion of `\lst@nolig`.

I located `\lst@nolig`'s definition in `listings.sty` but its purpose is not clear to me and I'm not sure why this happens only when a token preceeds a comma.

`\let\lst@nolig\@empty` is a solution, but of course that's not satisfactory.

**What's the proper solution to the problem?**

*Also, what's going on with the `\lst@nolig`?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is indeed the comma, because in this case `\index` is passed `foobar\lst@nolig`. Redefine, locally, `\lst@nolig` to avoid the issue.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\lstindexmacro}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \def\lst@nolig{}%
  \index{#1@{\ttfamily#1}}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\lstset{index={foobar,baz}}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
foobar, baz
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The standard definition of `\lstindexmacro` is just `\index{#1}`, but this will give sorting problems. Here is the produced `.idx` file:

```latex
\indexentry{foobar@{\ttfamily  foobar}}{1}
\indexentry{baz@{\ttfamily  baz}}{1}
```

Comment: Thanks! Local redefinition is what I ended up doing. I still feel like `listings` should be able to indicize the `foobar` token with no trailing extra macros, or provide some options to correctly handle the comma (I searched and found nothing). Could this actually be a bug in `listings`? I'll wait a bit just in case someone else chimes in.